# How does one add the digits of a large number?

Tags: python

I have been trying to add the individual digits of a larger number for a while now, and I'm having some trouble. I was wondering if anyone could help me.

For example, say I have the number `23455869654325768906857463553522367235` and I want to add all the digits. (`2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 8 + 6...`) In addition, how would I add specific ones like, for example, digits 5-10 (`8 + 6 + 9 + 6 + 5 + 4`).

I'm aware of the `len` function and printing parts of strings and such, but nothing that could easily add all the digits individually of a 100+ digit number.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Any code of what you've tried?

Comment: Are you also aware that you can iterate over strings?  `sum([int(i) for i in '1234'])`.

Comment: Really? Wow, I feel a bit dumb, haha.. That helps, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a more verbose method than `sum()` Simply get each char in the string, make it a number and add it.

```
total = 0                          #Have total number
bigNumber = str(45858383)          #Convert our big number to a string
for number in bigNumber:           #for each little number in our big number
    total = total + int(number)    #add that little number to our total
print(total)                       #Print our total
```

And if you'd like to do only certain spots:

```
total = 0                           #Have total number
bigNumber = str(123456789)          #Convert our big number to a string
startPlace = 2                      #Start
endPlace = 4                        #End
for i in xrange(startPlace,endPlace):    #have i keep track of where we are, between start and end
    total = total + int(bigNumber[i])    #Get that one spot, and add it to the total
print(total)                       #Print our total
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks for the help and thanks again for the commenting, learned what I was looking for and really learned how to do it which was the main goal. :)

Answer (score 1):

Treat it as a string, and `sum` the individual numbers.  Slice if you need to.

```
sum(map(int,str(12345)))
Out[183]: 15

sum(map(int,str(12345)[1:3]))
Out[184]: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

one more alternative is to use build in list([iterable]) function

```
bigNumber = '23455869654325768906857463553522367235'
print sum(int(x) for x in list(bigNumber))
print sum(int(x) for x in list(bigNumber)[5:11])
```